# Weird Backtrace After a Call Instruction Targeting Signal Functions

Tags: linux, gdb, signals, backtrace, libdl

I tried to trace `evince-3.28.4` execution using `GDB`. There is a `callq` instruction at some point in `libdl`, which is shown below (i.e., at `_dl_lookup_symbol_x+840`):

```
 │0x7ffff7de03f5 <_dl_lookup_symbol_x+837>        mov    %rbx,%rsi                              │
>│0x7ffff7de03f8 <_dl_lookup_symbol_x+840>        callq  0x7ffff7df0b00 <_dl_signal_cexception> │
 │0x7ffff7de03fd <_dl_lookup_symbol_x+845>        mov    %rbx,%rdi                              │
```

When the execution reaches here, the backtrace is as follows:

```
#0  0x00007ffff7de03f8 in _dl_lookup_symbol_x (undef_name=0x7ffff744fa23 "gtk_progress_get_type", undef_map=0x7ffff7ffe170, ref=0x7fffffffd8d8, symbol_scope=0x7ffff7ffe4f8, version=0x0, type_class=0, flags=2, skip_map=<optimized out>) at dl-lookup.c:857
#1  0x00007ffff4bd6da6 in do_sym (flags=2, vers=0x0, who=0x7ffff486d48e <g_module_symbol+126>, name=0x7ffff744fa23 "gtk_progress_get_type", handle=0x7ffff7ffe170)
at dl-sym.c:151
#2  0x00007ffff4bd6da6 in _dl_sym (handle=0x7ffff7ffe170, name=0x7ffff744fa23 "gtk_progress_get_type", who=0x7ffff486d48e <g_module_symbol+126>) at dl-sym.c:254
#3  0x00007fffefcdf0e4 in dlsym_doit (a=a@entry=0x7fffffffdb20) at dlsym.c:50
#4  0x00007ffff4bd72df in __GI__dl_catch_exception (exception=exception@entry=0x7fffffffdab0, operate=0x7fffefcdf0d0 <dlsym_doit>, args=0x7fffffffdb20)
at dl-error-skeleton.c:196
#5  0x00007ffff4bd736f in __GI__dl_catch_error (objname=0x5555557d44a0, errstring=0x5555557d44a8, mallocedp=0x5555557d4498, operate=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>) at dl-error-skeleton.c:215
#6  0x00007fffefcdf735 in _dlerror_run (operate=operate@entry=0x7fffefcdf0d0 <dlsym_doit>, args=args@entry=0x7fffffffdb20) at dlerror.c:162
#7  0x00007fffefcdf166 in __dlsym (handle=handle@entry=0x7ffff7ffe170, name=name@entry=0x7ffff744fa23 "gtk_progress_get_type") at dlsym.c:70
#8  0x00007ffff486d48e in _g_module_symbol (symbol_name=0x7ffff744fa23 "gtk_progress_get_type", handle=0x7ffff7ffe170) at ../../../../gmodule/gmodule-dl.c:163
#9  0x00007ffff486d48e in g_module_symbol (module=module@entry=0x5555557d44c0, symbol_name=symbol_name@entry=0x7ffff744fa23 "gtk_progress_get_type", symbol=symbol@entry=0x7fffffffdba0) at ../../../../gmodule/gmodule.c:800
#10 0x00007ffff728f55e in _gtk_module_has_mixed_deps (module_to_check=module_to_check@entry=0x0) at ../../../../gtk/gtkmodules.c:594
#11 0x00007ffff728f703 in find_module (name=0x5555557db040 "gail") at ../../../../gtk/gtkmodules.c:227
#12 0x00007ffff728f703 in load_module (name=0x5555557db040 "gail", module_list=0x0) at ../../../../gtk/gtkmodules.c:292
#13 0x00007ffff728f703 in load_modules (module_str=module_str@entry=0x5555557d44f0 "gail:atk-bridge") at ../../../../gtk/gtkmodules.c:423
#14 0x00007ffff728fb64 in _gtk_modules_init (argc=0x0, argv=<optimized out>, gtk_modules_args=0x5555557d44f0 "gail:atk-bridge") at ../../../../gtk/gtkmodules.c:544
#15 0x00007ffff726786b in do_post_parse_initialization (argc=0x0, argv=0x0) at ../../../../gtk/gtkmain.c:755
#16 0x00007ffff726786b in post_parse_hook (context=<optimized out>, group=<optimized out>, data=0x5555557d0cd0, error=0x7fffffffdd98) at ../../../../gtk/gtkmain.c:798
#17 0x00007ffff54768a8 in g_option_context_parse (context=<optimized out>, argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, error=<optimized out>)
at ../../../../glib/goption.c:2165
#18 0x0000555555573386 in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at main.c:275
```

But when I enter `ni` (to jump to the next assembly instruction), it turns into this:

```
#0  0x00007ffff4bd72cd in __GI__dl_catch_exception (exception=exception@entry=0x7fffffffdab0, operate=0x7fffefcdf0d0 <dlsym_doit>, args=0x7fffffffdb20)
at dl-error-skeleton.c:194
#1  0x00007ffff4bd736f in __GI__dl_catch_error (objname=0x5555557d44a0, errstring=0x5555557d44a8, mallocedp=0x5555557d4498, operate=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>) at dl-error-skeleton.c:215
#2  0x00007fffefcdf735 in _dlerror_run (operate=operate@entry=0x7fffefcdf0d0 <dlsym_doit>, args=args@entry=0x7fffffffdb20) at dlerror.c:162
#3  0x00007fffefcdf166 in __dlsym (handle=handle@entry=0x7ffff7ffe170, name=name@entry=0x7ffff744fa23 "gtk_progress_get_type") at dlsym.c:70
#4  0x00007ffff486d48e in _g_module_symbol (symbol_name=0x7ffff744fa23 "gtk_progress_get_type", handle=0x7ffff7ffe170) at ../../../../gmodule/gmodule-dl.c:163
#5  0x00007ffff486d48e in g_module_symbol (module=module@entry=0x5555557d44c0, symbol_name=symbol_name@entry=0x7ffff744fa23 "gtk_progress_get_type", symbol=symbol@entry=0x7fffffffdba0) at ../../../../gmodule/gmodule.c:800
#6  0x00007ffff728f55e in _gtk_module_has_mixed_deps (module_to_check=module_to_check@entry=0x0) at ../../../../gtk/gtkmodules.c:594
#7  0x00007ffff728f703 in find_module (name=0x5555557db040 "gail") at ../../../../gtk/gtkmodules.c:227
#8  0x00007ffff728f703 in load_module (name=0x5555557db040 "gail", module_list=0x0) at ../../../../gtk/gtkmodules.c:292
#9  0x00007ffff728f703 in load_modules (module_str=module_str@entry=0x5555557d44f0 "gail:atk-bridge") at ../../../../gtk/gtkmodules.c:423
#10 0x00007ffff728fb64 in _gtk_modules_init (argc=0x0, argv=<optimized out>, gtk_modules_args=0x5555557d44f0 "gail:atk-bridge") at ../../../../gtk/gtkmodules.c:544
#11 0x00007ffff726786b in do_post_parse_initialization (argc=0x0, argv=0x0) at ../../../../gtk/gtkmain.c:755
#12 0x00007ffff726786b in post_parse_hook (context=<optimized out>, group=<optimized out>, data=0x5555557d0cd0, error=0x7fffffffdd98) at ../../../../gtk/gtkmain.c:798
#13 0x00007ffff54768a8 in g_option_context_parse (context=<optimized out>, argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, error=<optimized out>)
at ../../../../glib/goption.c:2165
#14 0x0000555555573386 in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at main.c:275
```

As can be seen, after a simple call and return, 4 elements are popped off the stack. Perhaps there is something special about the <`_dl_signal_cexception()`, `__GI__dl_catch_exception()`> pair. The stack is changed by some means other than `call` or `return`. It seems that `_dl_signal_cexception()` finally leads to a `__longjmp()` function at `../sysdeps/x86_64/__longjmp.S` which modifies the backtrace. Can someone describe the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As can be seen, after a simple call and return, 4 elements are popped off the stack. Perhaps there is something special about the `_dl_signal_cexception()` `__GI__dl_catch_exception()`pair. The stack is changed by some means other than call or return.

Correct: the `_dl_signal_exception` doesn't `return`, it uses `longjmp` to transfer control not to its caller, but to its callers callers ... caller.

> It seems that `_dl_signal_cexception()` finally leads to a `__longjmp()`

Correct.

> Can someone describe the process?

You appear to not understand what `longjmp` does. Reading its [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3p.html) and/or [this example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact22-concept-of-setjump-and-longjump/) should help.

**Update:**

> this approach for transition in control flow is somehow insane even compared to simple gotos ... any other cases that I should consider?

Other "interesting" control transfers are via `makecontext`, `setcontext` and `swapcontext` family of functions, and (in C++) `throw` and `catch` are pretty much equivalent to `setjmp` and `longjmp`.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I am trying to synthesize the call stack using `Pin`. I handled situations such as `tail call elimination`s and `inline function call`s, but this approach for transition in control flow is somehow insane even compared to simple `goto`s and was unpredictable. Do you know any other cases that I should consider?